# Como enviar todos os arquivos de uma pasta via FTP no PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

Preciso pegar todos arquivos de uma pasta local e envia via FTP para uma pasta no servidor.

Explicação:

Tenho uma pasta com imagens (.jpg) de produtos que no momento do cadastro gero um ID no banco de dados mysql e coloco como nome na imagem.

E preciso pegar estas imagens e levar ate um outro servidor via FTP, so que não seria funcional precisar selecionar ou ate mesmo fazer manual o processo, com isto preciso de uma forma via programação PHP que eu agende depois no cron do servidor para executar.

Agradeço

Comment: Como você está fazendo? (Código)

Answer (score 1):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Um exemplo de upload:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = '<endereço do ftp>';
$ftp_user_name = '<usuario>';
$ftp_user_pass = '<senha>';

//Arquivo de origem
$file = '/pasta/no/servidor/de/origem/imagem.jpg';

//Aonde será salvo
$remote_file = 'pasta/no/servidor/remoto/imagem.jpg';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Upload de $file completo\n";
} else {
    echo "Erro ao enviar o $file\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Se quiser enviar todos de uma pasta pode usar `opendir` ou `scanndir` ou [`FileSystem`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)